# 14.04 Onboard on-screen keyboard: Only Greek / math keys

Tags: multi-touch, touchscreen, onboard, onscreen-keyboard

So I have Onboard working properly; e.g. comes up when I need it, fades out when I don't. However, somewhere along the line, I lost my standard QWERTY, and am stuck with Greek / math symbols (insert it's-all-Greek-to-me joke here).

Images here: https://i.stack.imgur.com/mOnMX.jpg

Possibly related: I do not see the arrow-crosshairs to enable me to move the keyboard around. I can resize with mouse; but cannot *move* the keyboard around the screen via mouse or touch. It does, however, move out of the way of the window requesting its use when it pops up.